# What is this surface? and how do you deal with the question if you don't know how this surface looks like?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals

> Given that $\vec F=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}(x,y,z)$. 
> And $S = \{(x,y,z)| z = 1-\frac{(1-x^2-y^2)^{100}}{2}, x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$. 
> With a normal that has a positive $z$ component. 
> And 
> $L=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2=1, z=0 \}$
> with direction against the clock arrows if we look from above. 
> Find: 
> $\oint_{\partial S}\vec F \cdot d\vec r$ 
> $\oint_L\vec F \cdot d \vec r$ 
> $\iint_S \vec F\cdot \hat ndS$

The first part of the question was to prove that $\nabla \cdot \vec F=0$ and  $\nabla \times \vec F=(0,0,0)$, and that gives me a hint that I need to use gauss and stokes theorems. 
But, in order to use gauss theorem, I need to know if $S$ is closed or not, and if not close it. and I know I have a problematic point in $(0,0)$. 

In order to use stokes theorem, I need to know that $\vec F \in C^1$ on the curve and on the surface, and on top of that I must "see" the surface so I decide how I'm going to use it and which ways, like for example if I use stokes on a cylinder surface, I need to do it twice, but if I do it on half of a ball, I can just do it on the circle curve and it will give me the flux. 
If I could use stokes here the first two integrals will actually give me $0$, (and it's the final answer), and the third one I will need to use gauss, but I have no idea why and how can I use them when I can't visualize the surface $S$ as I've explained. 
I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S = \{(x,y,z)| z = 1-\frac{(1-x^2-y^2)^{100}}{2}, x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$

Please note that at $r = 0, z = \frac{1}{2}$ and as $r$ increases, $z$ increases with $z = 1$ at $r = 1$.

So it is a surface which is between $\frac{1}{2} \leq z \leq 1$ and is open at $z = 1$ (in absence of a better name for the surface, draw a far resemblance with a paraboloid surface that opens up)

Also as you mentioned, the curl of the vector field is zero over the domain of $S$ and so is divergence.

To apply divergence theorem, close the surface with disk $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ at $z = 1$.

The outward normal vector is $(0, 0, 1)$. So flux through the disk surface is,

$I = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1 + r^2)^{3/2}} \ r \ dr \ d\theta$

And to find flux through surface $S$, we subtract flux through the disk from flux through closed surface, which is zero.

For line integral over $L$, parametrize the curve as,

$c(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

And line integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \vec F(r(t)) \cdot c'(t) \ dt$

which should again be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, took me long enough to understand what you meant about $S$, and now I can understand how you closed it, and how you used the divergence theorem. But I'm still wondering about $\partial S$, if it's $x^2 + y^2 =1$ could I say that $\oint_{\partial S}F \cdot dr = - \iint (\nabla \times F)\cdot n dS=0$? the minus doesn't matter really matter but I added it because it's the top curve of the surface so I go into an opposite direction of normal stokes theorem. And I'm still trying to find a way to do the integral on $L$ without parametrization since the final answer is $0$..

Comment: $\int_{\partial S}F \cdot dr$ is of course zero as the curl is defined over $S$ and the curl is zero. As far as over $L$, we have an issue at $(0, 0, 0)$ so please do line integral but note that the moment you find $\vec F(r(t) \cdot c'(t)$, you are done as that is zero.

Comment: How do you find $\partial S$? is it by plugging the border values of the flask which is the circle $x^2 + y^1 = 1$? if I can understand how we find that curve, couldn't we find any surface that has that curl in it and use stokes theorem on it and say it's equal to our integral?

Comment: $\partial S$ is boundary of $S$, which is at $z = 1$. Curl is zero over $S$ so line integral is zero. Is that clear? I will come to $L$ later.

Comment: Sorry for bugging again, what do you mean by curl is zero? don't we get at $z=1$ the upper circle of the flask?

Comment: Yes but by Stokes' theorem, $\displaystyle \int_{\partial S} \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat n \ dS$. As curl is zero, line integral is zero.